# PDO, PHP небольшой вопрос.

Tags: pdo, php

Есть таблица, в ней поля text и id

Из неё извлекаю данные следующим образом:

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `news` ");
$db->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
$result->execute();
if($result->rowCount() > 0){
    while($res = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){

        echo '<div class = "post">';
        echo ' <h1>', $res['title'] , '</h1>';
         echo '     <ul class = "meta"><li>Автор: ', $res['author'] ,'  Дата ', $res['date'], '</li></ul><div class="the-excerpt">', $res['text'], '</div></div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Как нужно преобразовать этот код, что бы данные выводились с максимального значения ID и далее по уменьшению?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: @Etki спасибо) я думал тут какие то свои причуды, а оказывается пиши и пиши, как на простом mysql_query